# determine listbox items origin

Tags: c#, winforms, list, object, .net-4.0

I'm working on an application of which requires me to have one list-box to hold data.

I'm having a little issue when deleting an object from a list-box. The issue comes into play when I fill the list-box with items from TWO separate lists.

Normally to delete the object I would get it's index and then remove it from the list in a separate class then reload the list-box to reflect the changes but in certain instances I need to fill the list-box with objects from two different lists and determining the origin of the object to delete from one of the two lists, well I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

this code is populating the list-box control.
//clear all items in the listbox
            ViewListBox.Items.Clear();

```
        //create the lists
        List listOfPickups = visits.listPickups();
        List listOfdeliveries = visits.listDeliveries();
        //populate
        ViewListBox.Items.AddRange(listOfPickups.ToArray());
        ViewListBox.Items.AddRange(listOfdeliveries.ToArray());
```

this is how i delete when i am only loading the listbox from one list.

```
        if (ViewListBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            EditSelectBtn.Enabled = false;
            DeleteSelectBtn.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("are you sure you want to delete the selected item?", "Are You Sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                visits.removePickup(this.ViewListBox.SelectedIndex);
                //refresh listbox.
                updateList("pickups");
            }
            else
            {
                //clicked no so do nothing!
                ViewListBox.ClearSelected();
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appretiated.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define type of selected item, and remove it from list with simple condition. Also removing by index will not help you here. Pass whole object instead

```
object item = ViewListBox.SelectedItem;

if (item is Pickup)
    visits.removePickup(item);
else
    visits.removeDelivery(item);
```

If items have same type, then use some other way to get item type (e.g. value of some property).

**UPDATE** One catch - you can determine item origin by comparing `SelectedIndex` with `listOfPickups` length, because you are adding pickup items first. If index is greater, than pickups count, then you are removing delivery. Subtract pickups count from selected index to get index of delivery item you need to remove.

```
List<Pickup> listOfPickups = visits.listPickups();
List<Delivery> listOfdeliveries = visits.listDeliveries();
ViewListBox.Items.AddRange(listOfPickups.ToArray());
ViewListBox.Items.AddRange(listOfdeliveries.ToArray());
//...

if (ViewListBox.SelectedIndex < listOfPickups.Count)
{
   // this is a Pickup
   visits.removePickup(ViewListBox.SelectedIndex);
}
else
{
   // this is a delivery
   int deliveryIndex = ViewListBox.SelectedIndex - listOfPickups.Count;
   visits.removeDelivery(deliveryIndex);
}
```

Comment: How would I go about implementing that? Sorry, if I'm going to be honest, I have never worked with lists before and well I'm learning but with limited time left.(a day) Teaches me for leaving things to the last minute. Never learn. - the update part? Thank you.

Comment: What type your lists have? Is it generic `List<T>` classes? What type of `T` then? Are your Delivery and Pickup items different classes, or not?

Comment: Hi, delivery and pickup are in two seperate classes. Every time i create a 'visit' i create a new pickup/delivery object of which gets added into a list in the visits class. these are the lists          private List<Pickup> pickups = new List<Pickup>();
        private List<Delivery> deliveries = new List<Delivery>();

Comment: I've added sample for removing items by index. BTW do Delivery and Pickup classes have same base class?

Comment: Perfect! Cannot thank you enough for the huge amount of help you have given me! It helps me in other areas too! Thanks again Sir.